# Connect to Database and Insert data - Php & MySQL -

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm starting to study php and mysql, I start with this simple module that include:

> 1. Create a Database connection; (run)
> 2. Connect to DataBase; (not give output message, probably not work)
> 3. Insert data; (not work)

**Question:**
Why it is not working correctly?

I create this simple PHP page (filename: **inizio.php**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="it" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Pagina di inizio</title>
</head>

<body style="width: 672px; height: 289px">

<p class="auto-style1" style="width: 293px; height: 24px">Titolo centrato della pagina</p>
        <form method="post" action="inserimento.php" style="width: 674px; height: 130px">
        Inserisci il nome:<input name="nome" type="text" /><br />
        Inserisci il cognome:<input name="cognome" type="text" /> <br />
        <br />
        <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Invia" /><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After I create this php script (filename **inserimento.php**):

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='root';
$database='test_youtube';

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
if (!$connection)
{
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
else
{
    die("...Connesso con successo al Server!");
}

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_select)
{
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
else 
{
    die("...Connesso con successo al Database!");
}

$query="insert into users(firstname, lastname)VALUES('".$_REQUEST['nome']."','".$request['cognome']."')";
if (!mysqli_query($query,$db_select))
{print("errore inserimento dati");
}
?>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: you have put `die()` in `else` too even if it's connecting properly.

Comment: `die()` it's not like `echo()` or `print()`! In else you must change `die()` with `echo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `die()` like following in your php file:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connect failed: ", mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query="insert into users(firstname, lastname)VALUES('".$_REQUEST['nome']."','".$_REQUEST['cognome']."')";
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection ,$query))
{
    print("Success!");
}
```

Comment: give error to $query, can you check the query please?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: request in C:\Apache24\htdocs\inserimento.php on line 37

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\inserimento.php on line 39
 errore inserimento dati

Comment: Updated! Please check.

Answer (score -1):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test_youtube");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO data_entry_users (user_name,user_password) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['nome']."','".$_REQUEST['cognome']."')");
mysqli_close($con);
```